# How to combine php code as hyperlink

Tags: php

I am trying to combine a code used to pull name of a store for my site with a word, and it is seperating the store name and word and not forming a hyperlink.

For example it will read..............**6pm** deals, but only hyperlink the store name, here is code that pulls the store name........

```
<div class="store-name">
                        <?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, ' ', ', ', ''); ?> 
                    </div>
```

I want it to say **6pm deals** and hyperlink entire term.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="store-name"><a href=""><?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, APP_TAX_STORE, ' ', ', ', ''); ?>.....6pm deals</a></div>
```